# Uwp Certificate build pipeline import error

Tags: azure, uwp

I use the below script to import a certificate in a pipeline build process,
Powershell script:

```
param($PfxFilePath, $Password)

$absolutePfxFilePath = Resolve-Path -Path $PfxFilePath
Write-Output "Importing store certificate '$absolutePfxFilePath'..."

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($absolutePfxFilePath, $Password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

Get below error:

. 'C:\JobAppAgent_work\1\s\JobApp\DevOps\Build\Import-PfxCertificate.ps1' -PfxFilePath $env:DOWNLOADSECUREFILE1_SECUREFILEPATH -Password ****
Importing store certificate 'C:\JobAppAgent_work_temp\DD.Job.Desktop_TemporaryKey.pfx'...
##[error]Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct.

This script was running fine when build was running on Azrure PipeLines. Now I create a private Agent pool  that runs on a Window 10 VM.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the certificate is valid and has not expired. You can check the expiration date of the certificate by double-clicking on it and viewing the details.

Check that the certificate is properly installed on the machine where the build is being performed. If the certificate is not installed, it will not be available for use in the build process.

Make sure that the certificate is correctly referenced in the build pipeline. This may involve specifying the path to the certificate file or the thumbprint of the certificate.

If you are using a self-signed certificate, make sure that it is trusted by the machine where the build is being performed. To do this, you will need to install the certificate in the trusted root certification authorities store on the machine.

If you are using a certificate from a certificate authority (CA), make sure that the CA is trusted by the machine where the build is being performed. This may involve installing the root certificate of the CA on the machine.

This is a PowerShell script that imports a certificate from a file with a given password into the "MY" store in the current user's certificate store. The certificate is imported using the Import method of the X509Certificate2 class, which takes as input the path to the certificate file, the password, and a set of key storage flags. The script then creates an X509Store object representing the "MY" store in the current user's certificate store, opens the store in read-write mode, adds the imported certificate to the store, and closes the store.

This script assumes that the certificate file is in the Personal Information Exchange (PFX) format, which is a common format for storing certificates and their private keys. PFX files are often used to export or import certificates, and they can be password-protected for added security.

Verify that the password you are using to import the certificate is correct. It's possible that the password has been changed or entered incorrectly.

Check that the certificate file has not been damaged or modified in any way. If the file has been altered, it may be causing the import to fail.

Make sure that the certificate file is accessible to the machine where the script is being run. If the file is on a network share or another machine, check that the machine has the necessary permissions to read the file.

If the certificate file is password-protected, make sure that the password has not expired or been revoked.

Try running the script with different key storage flags to see if that has any effect on the error. For example, you could try using "Exportable" instead of "PersistKeySet" as the key storage flag.

Comment: Thank you for ur response. Th certificate is not expired and its password is correct. We are usinf Self-signed certificate. So how do I  install the certificate in the trusted root certification authorities store on the machine?